# Correct way to make custom changes in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning bootstrap, and I am busy going through the training material on W3Schools. However, I'm confused about something:

Let's say I am adding a button to my site using this code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Basic</button>
```

But lets say that I want this button pink instead of grey...
Does Bootstrap have a specific way that I am supposed to make minor changes like colors etc? Or will it be correct if I were to add a custom class to the button and change the colors through my custom stylesheet?

Like so:

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn mypinkbutton">Basic</button>
```

CSS

```
.mypinkbutton {background:#FFC0CB;}
```

**Basically... Do I just make any changes that I want like I would normally do in my style.css or does it work differently in bootstrap?**

Comment: I think you're looking for bootstrap theming https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 3 and 4 you should customize all components in sass/less and compile all sources:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

It's best way to customize bootrap.

You can also generate custom bootstrap resources here(for bootstrap 3): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/
However, it's not flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to do this would be to use [Bootstrap theming](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/theming/).

Bootstrap includes a number of [color variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/theming/#color) and, for buttons (and many other components), a bunch of [pre-made classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/buttons/#examples) that can be used to apply these colors. For example, a "primary" button looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

The `.btn-primary` class applies the "primary" color from the `$theme-colors` Sass map, which is `#007bff` by default (blue). To change that color, you can either change the hex value directly or (even better) create a custom Sass file and then [modify the map](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/theming/#modify-map) with your own colors.

All that said, there's technically nothing "wrong" with how you've done it in your question – that'll still work if all you want to do is change the color in that particular case. But the whole advantage of Bootstrap is that it's a *framework* that makes managing and maintaining things like this much easier across a large project, so best practice is to use what it provides for these situations.